# make dictionary with keys equal to all ASCII characters

Tags: javascript, ascii, associative-array

I need to create a dictionary with a key for each character which can exist in ASCII between 0x20 and 0x7F.  So "a", "b", "A", "*" etc and the value must be an empty array.

What is the most efficient way to do this in Javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use a `for` loop for it.

```js
var object = {},
    i;

for (i = 32; i < 128; i++) {
    object[String.fromCharCode(i)] = [];
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store ascii character in variable, split it and reduce:

```
var chars = " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~";
var dict = chars.split('').reduce(function(r, ch) {
    r[ch] = [];
    return r;
}, {});
```

If you are looking for the most efficient way to do this, simply use object literal:

```
var dict = {
    "~": [], "}": [], "|": [], "{": [], "z": [], "y": [], "x": [], "w": [],
    "v": [], "u": [], "t": [], "s": [], "r": [], "q": [], "p": [], "o": [],
    "n": [], "m": [], "l": [], "k": [], "j": [], "i": [], "h": [], "g": [],
    "f": [], "e": [], "d": [], "c": [], "b": [], "a": [], "`": [], "_": [],
    "^": [], "]": [], "\\": [], "[": [], "Z": [], "Y": [], "X": [], "W": [],
    "V": [], "U": [], "T": [], "S": [], "R": [], "Q": [], "P": [], "O": [],
    "N": [], "M": [], "L": [], "K": [], "J": [], "I": [], "H": [], "G": [],
    "F": [], "E": [], "D": [], "C": [], "B": [], "A": [], "@": [], "?": [],
    ">": [], "=": [], "<": [], ";": [], ":": [], "9": [], "8": [], "7": [],
    "6": [], "5": [], "4": [], "3": [], "2": [], "1": [], "0": [], "/": [],
    ".": [], "-": [], ",": [], "+": [], "*": [], ")": [], "(": [], "'": [],
    "&": [], "%": [], "$": [], "#": [], "\"": [], "!": [], " ": [],
};
```

Comment: why the console.log?  
Will this be more efficient than the previous answer?

Comment: @AdamKatz I think this is a little bit more efficient (because it avoids calling `fromCharCode` many times), but it is not a big deal for an array of length 95 :)

Comment: but you need to generate the string anyway.